# matplotlib data with indivisual label for points and color for sets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color indivisual points but output is all same color:

```
xa=[4,6,10,13]
ya=[4.5,9.5,6.5,6]
ca=[0,1,0,2]
colors=["#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0066"]
ax1 = plt.axes()

for i in range(len(xa)):
    ax1.plot(xa,ya, color=colors[ca[i]])
```

same is also true for

```
for i in range(len(xa)):
    ax1.scatter(xa,ya, color=colors[ca[i]])
```

ofc for plot its better to have one line color and different colors for each point.

Comment: The lines are being plotted on top of each other (as the data is not changing).

Comment: are you talking about the code with plot ?? first answer scatter one please
and I just realized this exact code workes elsewhere!!

Comment: Exact same problem for the scatter, for the example shown in the question. I'd imagine for the scatter you would want to do something like `ax1.scatter(xa, ya, color=[colors[i] for i in ca])` (not in a for loop)